# I want to send an array using $.ajax and receive it in a classic asp page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I have an array that have the id's of cities collected from select input

```js
var city = $('select[name="city"] :selected').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

and I want to send it to classic asp page that will insert the previous array into the database.
using this code

```vbs
for each city in Request.Form("city")
    Set rsaddcity = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsaddcity.Open "city_project", conn, 1, 2
    rsaddcity.AddNew
    rsaddcity.Fields.Item("cityid").Value = city
    rsaddcity.Fields.Item("projectid").Value = projectid
    rsaddcity.Update
    rsaddcity.Close()
    Set rsaddcity = Nothing
next
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried sendind this throught ajax but i think i have a problem with the array format i don't this classic asp undernstand the format that I sent.
Because i saw after debugging that the array in asp is seperated with commas ex : 55,53,60

Comment: If you sending a plain old HTTP POST you just need `city=55&city=53...` as the post body *(or using jQuery the `data` element of `$.ajax`)* etc, then in the asp page call `Request.Form("city")` as you are doing.

Comment: You could also just use [`$("form").serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to build a serialized string of all your form variables of which `city` will be sent. Even try `$("select[name='city']").serialize()` to just serialize the required values to `data`.

Comment: I'd just format URL for post as [url]?city=55,53,51 and let the server break up the city on the commas, as it generally does this anyway.

Comment: @CLaFarge No it doesn't an HTTP POST sends the same named value multiple times `city=55&city=53&city=51` when dealing with multiples of the same form field, it is this format the OP should be using otherwise more coding is required to split the values out. This way will work with a standard `For Next` loop as the OP has already implemented.

Answer (score -1):

```
aryCities = split(Request.Form("city"),",")
aryProjects = split(Request.Form("project"),",")
for i = 0 to ubound(aryCities)
    Set rsaddcity = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsaddcity.Open "city_project", conn, 1, 2        
    rsaddcity.AddNew
    rsaddcity.Fields.Item("cityid").Value = aryCities(i)
    rsaddcity.Fields.Item("projectid").Value = aryProjects(i)
    rsaddcity.Update
    rsaddcity.Close()
    Set rsaddcity = Nothing
next
```

Comment: Why? You can enumerate `Request.Form("city")` using `For Next` loop as the OP has already done. The issue is the OP needs to send the data tot he Classic ASP page formatted correctly so the `For` loop can enumerate it.